# updateOne does not update multiple fields and does not create new fields in a record

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using NodeJs and MongoDB atlas for saving/updating user profiles. However, the `updateOne` method does not update multiple fields and I do not know why! It only works for one variable and not for the whole record! Here is my code:

```js
app.post("/edit-profile", async (req, res) => {
  if(req.body.password || req.body.phoneNumber){
    res.status(401);
    res.send({"error": "this api is not for changing password or phoneNumber"})
  } else {
    console.log("let's update this user: id="+req.body.id)
    console.log(req.body)
    result = User.updateOne(
      { _id: ObjectId(req.body.id)},
      req.body,
      (error, result) => {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          res.status(400);
          res.send();
        } else {
          if (result.n > 0) {
            console.log("result")
            console.log(result)
            res.header({ sessionToken: "testToken" });
            res.send(req.body);
          } else {
            console.log("there is no user with this id")
            res.status(404);
            res.send({"message":"There is no user with this id!"});
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
});
```

for example whenever, when I have it works for

```json
{
    "id":"6253024ca9a2fb3a9a8d3675",
    "weight":888
}
```

but does not work for

```json
{
    "id":"6253024ca9a2fb3a9a8d3675",
    "height":999
}
```

only works for `weight` parameter and does not create a new field (`height`). Even I used multiple fields at the same time and got the same results.
Also, I have another API for updating the meals item and it has a similar structure and it works. Here is my code for this API:

```js
app.post("/edit-meals", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = mealSchema.validate(req.body);
  if (error) {
    res.status(400); // 400 bad request
    res.send(error.details[0].message);
  } else {
    const meal = await Meal.findOne({ title: req.body.title });
    if (meal) {
      Meal.updateOne({ title: req.body.title }, req.body, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(403);
          res.send;
        } else {
          res.send(req.body);
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404);
      res.send();
    }
  }
});
```

Although the `updateOne` works in the `edit meals` but it does not work in `edit user`. I would be grateful if anybody could help me through this.

Comment: Can you post schema for both user and meal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your `User` model has all of the fields defined. Mongoose will ignore all the properties that are not present inside the model.

So, check the `User` schema and see if there is `height` field defined.

Comment: That it... Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to remove this criterion and have a flexible structure?

Comment: Yup, you can specify `{ strict: false }` in you schema definition. By default, it is set to `true`. You can find more info here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

Answer (score 0):

```
    app.post("/edit-meals", async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = mealSchema.validate(req.body);
  if (error) {
    res.status(400); // 400 bad request
    res.send(error.details[0].message);
  } else {
    const meal = await Meal.findOne({ title: req.body.title });
    if (meal) {
      Meal.updateOne({ title: req.body.title }, {{$set:{field: value}}}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(403);
          res.send;
        } else {
          res.send(req.body);
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.status(404);
      res.send();
    }
  }
});
```

try this {field: value}

Comment: I did try that and it does not work! I do not know why

Comment: I update Code try again using $set method

Comment: I have used $set as well, but based on the documents there is no need for using it anymore as my code works for meals without having $set.

Answer (score 0):

Use updateMany to update multiple documents in mongoDb.

```
updateMany({data})
```

To add a new field in mongodb document use

```
updateMany({_id: ObjectId(req.body.id)},{$set:{key:value}})
```